# Permissions issue with NFS mounted share

Tags: permissions, nfs, ubuntu-13.10

I have mounted an NFS network share successfully using Webmin. The share seems to be mounted correctly and working correctly. If I login as root I can browse the share just fine.

However, I cannot seem to give another user access to read/write to this network share. When I look at the permissions I can see that it is owned by root and the group crontab can use the share.

```
$ ls -las

4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    4096 Nov 11 23:35 .
4 drwxr-xr-x  23 root root    4096 Nov 11 23:35 ..
8 drwxrwx---+ 23 root crontab 4096 Feb 15  2013 private
```

I tried giving a user access by adding them to the crontab group.  However the user could not access the share.

```
$ groups

scott adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev crontab lpadmin sambashare

$ cd private/

-bash: cd: private/: Permission denied
```

So just to see whats going on I changed the user to the owner.  The user could then access the share.  Cool, but why didn't the group permissions work?

```
$ sudo chown scott:crontab private/    
$ ls -las

4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    4096 Nov 11 23:35 .
4 drwxr-xr-x  23 root root    4096 Nov 11 23:35 ..
8 drwxrwx---+ 23 scott crontab 4096 Feb 15  2013 private
```

How do I get the NFS mounted share to be accessible by any user in the group crontab?

Note: 
I originally posted this question on [ubuntu's stack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375776/cant-access-nfs-share-with-non-root-user?noredirect=1#comment480118_375776) but I'm not getting any responses.

Comment: your private folder permissions are using ACL note the + when you do ls -l.

Comment: Ahh good call, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the user group to the ACL.  I also modified the default group permissions so new files will also be accessible in the future.

Fist installed acl

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```

Changed the permissions

```
sudo setfacl -d -Rm g:nas:rwx  private/

# -d to change the directory default.
# -R for recursive
# -m g:nas:rwx to add the group to the ACL list for folder private/
```

I verified the changes:

```
sudo getfacl private/
```